# Ext.panel.Panel Items is not appearing

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, panel

I've defined a panel class* which is wrapped by another panel**. Somehow subclass' items are not rendering? I've tried several layouts and configs, as well tried to set flex config but none of those adjustment worked. Why it could be?

Thanks in advance...

(*) Panel:

```
Ext.define('AP.view.dashboard.BPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'bpanel',

    requires: [
        'Ext.layout.container.HBox',
        'Ext.layout.container.VBox',
        'Ext.ProgressBar'
    ],

        layout : {type  : 'vbox', align : 'stretch', pack: 'center'},

    items: [
        {
          xtype: 'panel',
          layout: 'vbox',
          items: [
              {
                  xtype: 'component',
                  html: 'TEXT'
              },
              {
                  xtype: 'component',
                  html: '20.82%'
              }
          ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'progressbar',
                    flex: 1,
                    cls: 'left-top-text progressbar-no-text',
                    height: 7.5,
                    hideMode: 'display',
                    margin: '0 15 0 0',
                    maxHeight: 10,
                    minHeight: 3,
                    value: 0.7,
                    text: ''
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            layout: 'vbox',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'component',
                                    html: '2016'
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'component',
                                    html: '3750'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            layout: 'vbox',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'component',
                                    html: '2017'
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'component',
                                    html: '4550'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            layout: 'vbox',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'component',
                                    html: 'Trend'
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'chartvisitors',
                                    flex: 1,
                                    cls: 'graph-analysis-right-inner-container right-value',
                                    bind: {
                                        store: '{visitors}'
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
});
```

(**) The panel above called by this one:

```
Ext.define('AP.view.dashboard.DashMid', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'dashmid',

    requires: [
        'Ext.layout.container.HBox',
        'Ext.layout.container.VBox',
        'HR.view.dashboard.APanel',
        'HR.view.dashboard.BPanel',
        'HR.view.dashboard.CPanel'
    ],

    layout: {type: 'hbox'},
    padding: 5,

    items: [
        {
           xtype: 'apanel'

        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: {type: 'vbox'},
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'bpanel'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'cpanel'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: There are a bunch of things wrong here. Post a working test case.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli what exactly wrong or what am i missing here? I've defined those panels through sencha admin dashboard sample and other several panels _(apanel & cpanel)_ works very well but except this one _-bpanel-_.

Comment: When you use `vbox` and `hbox` layout's, you have to explicitly set the width or use the `flex` property on child components. I believe not setting this will not render them, as they are not programmed to `fit` the space available.

Comment: I just read this [doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/guides/core_concepts/components.html#core_concepts-_-components_-_which_class_to_extend) and i think also I've problems about extended class. Therefore will have quick refactoring on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found solution depends on some other stackoverflow questions and NAmorim's comment. Unfortunately because of on-going refactoring I won't repost code snippets, otherwise you could be more confuse.

- The first mistake I've been done is about **extended classes**. I've crated nested panels. I had to extend several of them with `Container` class, instead of `Panel` class. So firstly refactored this step. Here is the [Sencha documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/guides/core_concepts/components.html#core_concepts-_-components_-_which_class_to_extend) that explains which class to extend.
- Secondly I've used `vbox` & `hbox` layouts but haven't stated any `flex` or `width` config. I've refactored those items through NAmorim's comment.

Thanks a lot.